# Make text element wrap before div

Tags: html, css

I have the following example set up: http://jsfiddle.net/Xj5cH/

```
<div id="box">
    <span id="text">This is some text. Hello World!</span>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>

#box {
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid;
}

#text {
    font-size:16px;
}

#sidebar {
    height:100%;
    width:50px;
    float:right;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

How would I get the text element to properly wrap before the sidebar div without explicitly setting its width?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Xj5cH/3/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right floated elements should appear **before** left side elements in the HTML.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/Xj5cH/1/)

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <span id="text">This is some text. Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Never knew that. Thanks a lot, will give a checkmark in 5 minutes!

Comment: Longest 5 minutes I've ever seen :)